# How to implement Undo Redo functionality for drawing smooth line using CCRenderTexture in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-x

I have made a functionality of drawing using CCSprite and CCRenderTexture. like

```
    Paint *paintColor=Paint::create("texture1@2x.png");
    draw=true;

    CCPoint end = touch->getPreviousLocationInView();
    end = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(end);

    target->begin();

    float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);

    for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
    {
        paintColor->color=globalColor;
        paintColor->setColor(paintColor->color);
        paintColor->scale=globalScale;
        paintColor->setScale(paintColor->scale);
        paintColor->opacity=globalOpacity;
        paintColor->setOpacity(paintColor->opacity);


        float difx = end.x - start.x;
        float dify = end.y - start.y;
        float delta = (float)i / distance;

        CCPoint p=ccp(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta));

        paintColor->originalPosition=p;
        paintColor->setPosition(paintColor->originalPosition);

        tempPath.path.push_back(p);
        tempPath.color=globalColor;
        tempPath.scale=globalScale;
        tempPath.opacity=globalOpacity;


        paintColor->visit();
}
```

but I want make undo functionality and want to remove last draw texture from CCRenderTexture. anyone can help me in making this functionality. Is there any method for removing sprite from CCRenderTexture.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did like follow.
whenever finish of a drawing (touchbegan, touchmove, touchend), I save image of RenderTexture in an array.
then, when I click undo button, I taked image from the array and visited it on RenderTexture.
I hope it helps you.